# Show that the norms $ | p | _1 $ and $ | p | _2$ are not equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

Let P be a vector space of polynomials with real coefficients. Show that the norms $ | p | _1 $ and $ | p | _2$ are not equivalent,  where $|p|_1$=max$ \{|p(t)|$; $0\leq t \leq 1 \}$ and $|p|_2$ = max $ \{|p(t)|$ ; $1 \leq t \leq 2\}$.

Comment: What have you tried? Take for example the simplest polynomials, the ones of the form $x^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show they aren't equivalent, it suffices to show that $\forall C > 0 \ \ \exists p \in P$ such that $|p|_2 > C|p|_1$. So  let $C>0$ be given. Note that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $|x^n|_1 = 1$, whereas $|x^n|_2 = 2^n$. So taking $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2^n > C$, and $p = x^n$ we see that $p$ witnesses the inequality $|p|_2 > C|p|_1$, as required.

Comment: Sure, just deny the claim and we have the example that contradicts.Thank you.